# Spring MultiAction Controller using XML alone

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is anyone having idea on how I can achieve multiaction controller in using XML config alone.Using annotations, it works perfectly.Just wanted to know, is it possible using xml config alone
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

WEB.XML

```
<web-app>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>xxxxServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>xxxxServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.process</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>xxxxServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.do</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

xxxxxServlet-servlet.xml

```
<beans>

<bean id="urlHandler"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" >
<property name="mappings">
<map>
<entry key="/validate.process" value="multiActionController"/>
<entry key="/sayHello.do" value="multiActionController"/>
<entry key="/index.do" value="multiActionController"/>
</map>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="multiActionController" class="controller.MyController" >
<property name="methodNameResolver" ref="myResolver" /> </bean>

<bean id="myResolver"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.PropertiesMethodNameResolver"
 lazy-init="default">
<property name="mappings">
<props>
<prop key="/validate.process">validateLogin</prop>
<prop key="/index.do">goToHome</prop>
<prop key="/sayHello.do">sayHello</prop> </props>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```